# Running an SSIS Package as a SQL Server Agent Job doesn't copy files?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package I can import into Integration Services on my server and run with no problems. All it does is copy files from a directory on the network to the server it is running on.

When I execute the SQL Agent Job it says the job ran successfully but no files are copied. I verify there are files in the source location and the destination path exists. I am also using absolute paths (no mapped drives).

Why doesn't it copy any files when I run it as a SQL Agent Job?

FYI - the source directory is actually on a UNIX box and to map a drive to that location you have to enter a user/password combination.

I have a feeling that the SQL Agent Job runs as NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT, which is not the user that has permission to the UNIX box. Is there a way to run the SQL job as a specific user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [create a **Credential**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190703.aspx), a [**SQL Agent Proxy**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175834.aspx), and then [assign the proxy account to the SQL Agent job step](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/). Proxy accounts are [specific to each subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187100%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (*e.g Powershell, CmdExec, SSIS, etc.*)

```sql
-- creating credential
USE [master]
GO
CREATE CREDENTIAL [Superuser] WITH IDENTITY = N'DOMAIN\account', SECRET = N'mypassword'
GO

-- creating proxy for CmdExec subsystem, adding principal
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_proxy @proxy_name=N'My custom proxy',@credential_name=N'Superuser', 
        @enabled=1
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name=N'My custom proxy', @subsystem_id=3
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_login_to_proxy @proxy_name=N'My custom proxy', @fixed_server_role=N'sysadmin'
GO

-- assigning job step to run as a given proxy user
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_id=N'0df2dac2-4754-46cd-b0bf-05ef65e1f87e', @step_id=1 , @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
    @proxy_name=N'My custom proxy'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. Just prior to seeing this I realized I had to do that. I did it through SSMS. I created a new credential with an identity of DOMAIN\Administrator. Then a new proxy using the credential with SSIS Package execution as a subsystem. The principles I added for the proxy were NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT and NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER.  I update the job step to "Run As" the new proxy. I run the package and still no files are copied and no errors are thrown. I guess I'm not sure what the credential identity should be or what the proxy principles should be. Do they seem correct? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work!! I had to make a local user account on the server with the same user/pass combination that you would use to map the network drive. I then used that as the identity for the credential and the job copied the files! Thanks again!!